# How to drag something an amount of pixel up using Codeception/Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using Codeception with the Selenium plugin to perform acceptance-tests. 
How can I make the WebGuy drag a div up by for example 50 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [executeJs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Selenium2#executeJs) to execute arbitrary JavaScript and you could include [jquery.simulate.js](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js) and simulate a drag with the following code:

`$('#element').simulate('drag', { dx: 50, dy: 50 });`